# SQL WITH AVG GROUP BY

Tags: sql, function, select, window, average

I have a Codecademy challenge, which I am miserably failing to resolve. I have two SQL tables. **places**:

```
id  username    place_id    review_date     rating  note    id  name    address     type    average_rating  price_point     total_reviews
136     @see.matt.run   11  2020-01-01  3   Not bad but don't think I'll go back    11  Phogeddaboudit  3 Glacier Hill Lane     Restaurant  4.1     $$  304
134     @pinkdeb    19  2020-01-06  2   They ruined all my lace fronts  19  Happy Hamper    11 Fair Oaks Parkway    Laundromat  4.6     $$$$    48
108     @pinkdeb    3   2020-01-14  1   I wish I could use some magic to make this place disappear  3   Abra Kebabra    193 Sauthoff Way    Restaurant  3.3     $   315
172     @hobgobble  1   2020-01-23  5   Great cut!!     1   Hairs to You    45-45 Queens Boulevard  Beauty  4.9     $$$     36
127     @sammyantha     1   2020-01-27  5   Hair has never looked better    1   Hairs to You    45-45 Queens Boulevard  Beauty  4.9     $$$     36
```

And **reviews**:

```
id  name    address     type    average_rating  price_point     total_reviews
1   Hairs to You    45-45 Queens Boulevard  Beauty  4.9     $$$     36
2   Doggonit!   100 Atlantic Ave    Pet Store   3.1     $$  52
3   Abra Kebabra    193 Sauthoff Way    Restaurant  3.3     $   315
4   Wok this Way    46 Crest Line Way   Restaurant  3.8     $$$     279
5   You've Got Nail     1912 Fisk Road  Beauty  4.8     $   47
```

I desire to output the username for the user with the lowest average ratings for each restaurant: places.name, reviews.username, average(rating(s)), like this:

```
name    username    Average Rating
Abra Kebabra    @ahohl  1.0
Boobie Trap     @crystallinez   1.0
```

EDIT

Solved the syntax errors. It appears the name for a CTE can't start with a number, even though Codecademy suggested just that. I now have two slightly different approaches as displayed below:

**1.**

```
WITH ratings AS (
  SELECT
    place_id,
    username,
    AVG(rating) AS "Average Rating"
  FROM reviews
  GROUP BY place_id, username
)
SELECT
  name AS "Restaurant",
  username AS "Username",
  MIN("Average Rating") OVER (
    PARTITION BY name
  ) AS "Average Rating"
FROM ratings
JOIN places
ON ratings.place_id = places.id
ORDER BY name;
```

**2.**

```
WITH ratings AS (
  SELECT
    place_id,
    username,
    AVG(rating) AS "Average Rating"
  FROM reviews
  GROUP BY place_id, username
)
SELECT
  name AS "Restaurant",
  username AS "Username",
  FIRST_VALUE("Average Rating") OVER (
    PARTITION BY name
    ORDER BY "Average Rating" ASC
  ) AS "Average Rating"
FROM ratings
JOIN places
ON ratings.place_id = places.id
ORDER BY name;
```

Both of these solutions have the same issue of displaying the users with the lowest average ratings.

```
name    username    Average Rating
Abra Kebabra    @ahohl  1.0
Abra Kebabra    @hannah.matrix  1.0
Abra Kebabra    @pinkdeb    1.0
Abra Kebabra    @shyamsworld    1.0
Abra Kebabra    @youngNOTold    1.0
Boobie Trap     @crystallinez   1.0
Boobie Trap     @evian_     1.0
Boobie Trap     @its_ozzy   1.0
Boobie Trap     @jared.knoys.best   1.0
Boobie Trap     @pinkdeb    1.0
Boobie Trap     @sammyantha     1.0
```

Yet, I would expect it to output just one, single user for each restaurant. Could someone please explain this too me.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Please define "most negative user name.  (3) Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: When you say" it does not generate any result"-what do you mean? You have syntax issues with your usage of CTE so it's hard to tell if you're getting an error or just getting an empty result set.

Comment: (1) I don't understand what you mean by " Tag with the database you are using.
(2) The username of the user that provides the reviews with the lowest rating.
(3) In what format would you like the sample data?

Comment: Codecademy (advanced) SQL course, does not produce (syntax) errors, but I am pretty confident that is the cause for what appears to be an empty result set. Although, I am much more interested in the logic of a functional answer, resolution of any syntax errors, might offer a starting point for me to wrestle some nore towards a solution.